# AttributeError: DescribeData: Method shapeType does not exist

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, python-script-tool, linear-referencing, attributeerror

Can anyone help me resolve this error?

> Traceback(most recent call last): File "*file.py", Line 15 in 
> if (arcpy.Describe(lyr).shapeType) == 'Polygon': AttributeError:
> DescribeData: Method shapeType does not exist

I am running the script below in an ArcToolbox.

````
aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
Map1 = aprx.listMaps("Map")[0]
#Map2 = aprx.listMaps("Map*")[1]
arcpy.env.workspace = r"T:\Risk Model\3rd Party Data\Crossings_aprx\SNV_CrossingsExport.gdb"
in_routes = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
#shapeType = arcpy.Describe(lyr).shapeType
for i,lyr in enumerate(Map1.listLayers()):
        if(arcpy.Describe(lyr).dataType)=='FeatureLayer':
            print(arcpy.Describe(lyr).shapeType)
#for i,lyr in enumerate(Map2.listLayers()):
        #if(arcpy.Describe(lyr).dataType)=='FeatureLayer':
            #print(arcpy.Describe(lyr).shapeType)
            
for i,lyr in enumerate(Map1.listLayers()):
        if (arcpy.Describe(lyr).shapeType) == 'Polygon':
            arcpy.LocateFeaturesAlongRoutes_lr(lyr, in_routes, "RouteId", "0 Feet", arcpy.env.workspace + "//" + "{}Located{}".format(lyr,i), "MapRouteId Line FMEAS TMEAS", "FIRST", "DISTANCE", "ZERO", "FIELDS", "M_DIRECTON")
        
        else:
            arcpy.LocateFeaturesAlongRoutes_lr(lyr, in_routes, "RouteId", "10 Feet", arcpy.env.workspace + "//" + "{}Located{}".format(lyr,i), "MapRouteId Point StationPoint", "FIRST", "DISTANCE", "ZERO", "FIELDS", "M_DIRECTON")```
````

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are almost there. As I mentioned in my comment, `shapeType` is a `Describe` property disclosed if the `Describe.dataType` is FeatureClass. Since you are working with a map and enumerating map layers, then this FeatureClass becomes feature layer.

As you did in your previous for loop, if you place `if(arcpy.Describe(lyr).dataType)=='FeatureLayer':` inside your second `for` loop to control `... .shapeType) == 'Polygon':` (and its `else` part), your script should work.